# Kafka producer can't create topics and throwing continuous error after creating Debezium MySQL connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Debezium as a CDC tool to stream data from MySql. After installing Debezium MySQL connector to Confluent OSS cluster, I am trying to capture MySQL bin_log changes into a Kafka topic. When I create a connector, after taking the snapshot of the database, I am left with a continuous series of error.

I checked MySql bin_log is ON and tried restarting schema-registry and connectors with different serializers. But I am getting the same errors.

Error logs show:

```
[2019-06-21 13:56:14,885] INFO Step 8: - Completed scanning a total of 955 rows from table 'mydb.test' after 00:00:00.086 (io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader:565)
[2019-06-21 13:56:14,886] INFO Step 8: scanned 1758 rows in 2 tables in 00:00:00.383 (io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader:601)
[2019-06-21 13:56:14,886] INFO Step 9: committing transaction (io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader:635)
[2019-06-21 13:56:14,887] INFO Completed snapshot in 00:00:01.055 (io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader:701)
[2019-06-21 13:56:14,965] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-5] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11 : {kbserver=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:968)
[2019-06-21 13:56:15,066] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-5] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 12 : {kbserver=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:968)
[2019-06-21 13:56:15,168] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-5] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 13 : {kbserver=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:968)
[2019-06-21 13:56:15,269] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-5] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 14 : {kbserver=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:968)
[2019-06-21 13:56:15,370] WARNDebezium [Producer clientId=producer-5] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 15 : {kbserver=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

The connector payload that I am sending is as follows:

```
{
      "name": "debezium-connector",
      "config": {
            "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
            "tasks.max": "1",
            "key.serializer": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "value.serializer": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "database.hostname": "localhost",
            "database.port": "3306",
            "database.user": "test",
            "database.password": "test@123",
            "database.whitelist": "mydb",
            "table.whitelist": "mydb.test",
            "database.server.id": "1",
            "database.server.name": "kbserver",
            "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
            "database.history.kafka.topic": "db-schema.mydb",
            "include.schema.changes": "true"
       }
    }
```

does someone know why this is happening or how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need to set [auto.create.topics.enable](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html)

Comment: I don't see any `ERROR`, just `WARN`. Does the connector actually fail, or are you just not getting data when you think you should be?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt No connector is not failing, it cannot automatically create topics for each table to produce messages.

Comment: @dmkvl  Enabling `auto.create.topics.enable` into broker config actually worked. Thank you so much for your suggestions.

Comment: did you solve your problem? I am having same issue, so looking if there is any update while bumped here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was hidden in the comment but was successful for me: it is sufficient to enable the autocreation of topic on the kafka broker.

If you use strimzi it is sufficient to modify the config section with the following property:

```
 auto.create.topics.enable: 'true'
```

The same configuration can be set in the kafka Connect. It a design choice where to set it.

If you do it on the broker it will be taken as a default and it will be valid for all the new request of creating a new kafka topic. If you set it on the Connect it will be valid only for the topic coming through the connect.

Hoewever I would avoid both those two solutions and create the topic manually in the setup. This is from the [debezium documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#about-the-debezium-sqlserver-connector-schema-change-topic)

> the topic you need to create need to have the same name as the
> , where serverName is the logical server name that is
> specified in the database.server.name

Answer (score 1):

Configure your connector to auto create topics: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/configuration/topic-auto-create-config.html

```
"topic.creation.enable": "true",
"topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "1",
"topic.creation.default.partitions": "1",
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to `database.whitelist` and `table.whitelist`. They are inconsistent.

It should be either `mydb` and `mydb.test` or `db` and `db.test` depending on the name of database.

Comment: Yeah, It was actually mistyped. It's corrected now. But the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error...
In my case, I had not created the "schema change topic" ahead of time.
See: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#about-the-debezium-sqlserver-connector-schema-change-topic

Once I created that topic, the error went away and data began streaming.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).